# XNA Content Manager not able to load files

Tags: c#, xna

I have a console application that I am trying to incorporate music with. So I decided to go with XNA Framework to get it done, because its the only thing **that I know** does this.

So I have the Content Manager RootDirectory pointed to a content project that I added. I have the mp3 file located in the project, however, an exception is always thrown saying that it cannot find it once I try to load it.

Is there a way to print out to the Console the contents of the Directory of where I have RootDirectory set to?

What other alternatives might there be if the problem is that I am using Xna, and it is not working because of it not being an Xna project?

Comment: _"I have a console application.... incorporate music...So I decided to go with XNA...because its the only thing that I know does this"_ - What's wrong with .NET's [`SoundPlayer.Play`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.play(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay, I was helping a buddy move... that why " that I know" that why I asked if there was an alternative... but let me test that out. I am familiar with Xna Framework that why I turned to it not knowing of the .Net Lib

Comment: No problem.  Hope the move went well

Comment: Thanks it did. Now the only limit to `SoundPlayer.Play` that I can see is that it only plays .wav, but converting an mp3 to .wav is easy in Audacity. The only downside is you lose the compression of mp3 format, but for me this works great.

Comment: Sweet.  Happy XNA'ing

Comment: Thanks, **if** you want to answer the question I will accept it and give ya upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use good ol' [`SoundPlayer.Play`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.play(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The Play method plays the sound using a new thread. If you call Play before the .wav file has been loaded into memory, the .wav file will be loaded before playback starts. You can use the LoadAsync or Load method to load the .wav file to memory in advance. After a .wav file is successfully loaded from a Stream or URL, future calls to playback methods for the SoundPlayer will not need to reload the .wav file until the path for the sound changes.